# A positive word for someone who is viewed like a sister, but isn’t one

Tags: synonyms

I’m trying to say that someone is a character’s ‘fake sister’ – that is, she was taken in by the character who now considers her to be as close as a sister – but it in a positive light.

*Fake sister* is obviously very negative; *pseudo-sister* is better, but still comes across as too negative for what I’m after. *Step-sister* won’t work because the two are not actually step-sisters.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are they a step-sister? Or a friend that is 'like a sister to me'?

Comment: The latter. Taken in by the female and now views the female as like a sister.

Comment: Alice is Betty's pretend sister.

Comment: I don't think you'll get anything more idiomatic than *like a sister*.

Comment: Thanks for the help fellows but I've gone for "honorary sister".

Comment: _Honorary sister_ is **not** a valid option for what you’re looking for here. It means something else. _Honorary_ means that you get a title or membership without putting in the work normally required to obtain that title. If you’re an honorary sister, you’ve been made a member of a convent without actually being a nun, or you’re a man who’s been made to feel like a member of an all-girls’ group of friends, or something along those lines. Someone who’s like a sister to you is not an honorary sister.

Comment: Actually, @nohat it is allowed and encouraged that OPs post their answers. Saying that, Lazerene it would be good to explain *why* you chose "honorary" and include a dictionary's reference to make the answer more self-contained.

Comment: It's worth noting that "honorary sister" are two words. In your position I would say "She's the sister I never had" or "We're closer than [real] sisters" or ["blood sisters"](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Blood%20Sister) See 2nd definition.

Comment: Contrary to what @JanusBahsJacquet said, the term "honourary sister" is valid here, by virtue of the fact that it is already in relatively common use with the OP's intended meaning.

Answer (score 3):

perhaps you could use "*soul-sister*" - according to the very trustworthy [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Soulsisters) a "soul-sister" is  :

> "Someone who fully understands you. Like a soulmate, but not someone
>   you want to marry and make babies with. The sister of your soul."

Another option is "sisters by heart".
It implies that there is no blood relation between you two, but you're close, like sisters.

Comment: I think this works, so +1. Can you find a better source than urban dictionary though?

Comment: Also fun, but informal: *sister from another mister*. Like *brother from another mother* not really used to talk about half-siblings.

Answer (score 0):

You could try ***surrogate sister***. [***Surrogate***](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/surrogate), in this case, would fall under this meaning:

> **surrogate**
>   *noun*
>
> 1- A substitute, especially a person deputizing for another in a specific role or office.
>   *she served as a surrogate for the President on a trip to South America*

It then has the connotation as someone acting as a sister but not necessarily being one.

Comment: _Especially a person deputizing for another in a specific role or office_ – that bit is quite important. A surrogate sister sounds like someone who is standing in for your real sister, implying that there _is_ a real sister, but she is not there for whatever reason, and someone else is substituting for her.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That could be positive. Then I would assume that this person is fulfilling the emotional need for this person of the sister role that is otherwise empty for whatever reason.

Comment: Yes, but we don’t know whether the character in question **has** an actual sister. To me, this would only work if there is (or was) an actual sister.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Good point. I wonder if it could work in the case of never having a sister, and feeling like there should be one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **virtual sister**, The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/virtual) defines *virtual* as follows:

> **almost, but not exactly or in every way**:
>
> *She was a virtual unknown before this movie.*
>
> *Snow brought Minneapolis to a virtual standstill yesterday.*

Using the adverb might sound better, e.g. "she was virtually his sister".

Answer (score 0):

I’d go with honorary sister. I have a friend who is like a sister and I call her big sister, or MHBS - My Honorary Big Sister. She calls me little sis.

Comment: That's a honor of a title, but I do see it mentioned in the comments.  This would benefit from a source.  Please do take a [tour] of the site and see the [help] for more information.